# MySQL help required for writing a query

Tags: mysql, select

I have number of records in database of which some are duplicates like

```
1 test 20-09-2011
2 main 20-09-2011
3 New  20-09-2011
4 test 20-09-2011
5 test 20-09-2011
6 test 20-09-2011
7 main 20-09-2011
8 main 20-09-2011
```

Now what i want is i get all three distinct records but with maximum id record out of them as below:

```
3 New  20-09-2011
6 test 20-09-2011
8 main 20-09-2011
```

Please suggest

Thanks all

Comment: I suggest you tell us what you've already tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *  
from table as t1
where t1.id = (select max(t2.id) from table as t2 where t1.name =t2.name)
```

where name is the second attribute of your table.